# How do you change the generator with the Rand crate?

Tags: random, rust, generator

"The Rust Rand Book" documents various generators. `thread_rng` claims to be cryptographically secure while others do not. But, I don't see any reference to how to change the generator. I also don't see any way to find out what generator is being used when using `thread_rng`. I would like to do testing on the various options available, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Q:** But, I don't see any reference to how to change the generator.

The word "change" is not really fitting here because you just create another RNG instance and use it. You can't *change* what `thread_rng` returns, for example.

Say you want to use [`SmallRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/rngs/struct.SmallRng.html). Before you can create random data with it, you have to create an instance. There are multiple ways to do it, with `from_entropy` being the easiest one. Alternatively you can provide your own seed with `from_seed`. Check the docs for more information.

After creating the RNG you can now generate random data, just like with what `thread_rng` returns:

```rust
let mut rng = SmallRng::from_entropy();
println!("{}", rng.gen::<u32>());
```

---

> **Q:** I also don't see any way to find out what generator is being used when using `thread_rng`.

[The docs for `ThreadRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) state: "`ThreadRng` uses the same PRNG as `StdRng` for security and performance". [The docs of `StdRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html) state:

> The PRNG algorithm in `StdRng` is chosen to be efficient on the current platform, to be statistically strong and unpredictable (meaning a cryptographically secure PRNG).
>
> The current algorithm used is the ChaCha block cipher with 20 rounds. This may change as new evidence of cipher security and performance becomes available.

Comment: What is the proper way to bring in imports for this? I have looked at the docs and copied examples (including imports) and everything I try results in: error[E0432]: unresolved import `rand::rngs::SmallRng`-- no `SmallRng` in `rngs`

Comment: Found in the documentation that you must enable the feature, changed my cargo.toml and it was successful: rand = { version = "0.7.3", features = ["small_rng"] }